# How to use dask bag and delayed to join 2 mapping functions?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dask

I have 2 functions: find_components and processing_partition_component

```
import random
import dask.bag as db

def find_components(partition):
  # it will return a list of components
  return [x for x in range(1, random.randint(1,10))]

def processing_partition_component(part_comp):
  print("processing %s" % part_comp)

partitions=['2','3','4']
```

I want to compute find_components() on a partition then get the output of each partition to generate tasks for processing_partition_component(). And the computation shouldn't wait for all the find_coponents() to be completed. In order words, the processing_partition_component() should be call right after one of processing_partition is finished.I have tried this, but it is not what I want:

```
db.from_sequence(partitions, partition_size=1).map(find_components).map(processing_partition_component).compute()
# Output:
processing [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
processing [1, 2]
processing [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

You can see the processing_partition_component() take the whole output of find_components() for example: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] as it in put. What I want is the task should fan-out after find_components() and each processing_partition_component() should only take 1 element like 1, 2, 3, 4 or 5. The expected print out is

```
processing 1
processing 2
processing 3
....
processing 1  # from another output of find_components
...
```

If this is multi-threaded the order of print out will be mixed up so Processing 1 can be printed out 3 times next to each other

I don't know how to do that using dask.bag and dask.delayed. I am using latest dask with python3

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dask bag will handle generators well

```
def f(partition):
    for x in partition:
        yield x + 1

my_bag.map_partitions(f).map(print)
```

This will add one to each element and then print it before moving onto the next element

Comment: the map_partition method doesn't exist in bag. I saw it is in dataframe only. I added more example on my question to show my expected outputs. Can you help me get the answer with the updated question? Thanks!

Comment: See the documentation for Dask Bag: http://docs.dask.org/en/latest/bag-api.html#dask.bag.Bag.map_partitions